# ASP.Net UserControl click event causes only postback, and doesn't fire event

Tags: c#, asp.net, onclick

When I attached My `UserControl`(contains Literal control, `imageButton` Control, labels, click event with imageButton control)
on the main page(default.aspx) dynamically,
Each `ImageButton` click Event of Usercontrol doesn't firing,
only refreshed.
Moreover, Breaking Point that I settled on the first line of click event logic of `ImageButton`
Doesn't work.
It seems doesn't pass its click event.
Please Help me

Below is UserControl's back code

```
 <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ContentHolder.ascx.cs" Inherits="TISSWeb.ContentHolder" %>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" BorderColor="#3399FF" BorderStyle="Solid" 
    BorderWidth="1px" width="100%">
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" Width="16px" 
        onclick="ImageButton1_Click" />
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" onclick="ImageButton2_Click" Width="16px"/>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Title"></asp:Label>
    &nbsp;
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton4" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/linknew.gif" />
    &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Date"></asp:Label>
    &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />  

    <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" style="overflow:hidden;height:60px;">
        <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Panel>

//below is C#(asp.net) Code


protected void ImageButton2_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
//below if is where I settled the Break Point
    if (starred == "1")
    {
        starred = "0";
        ImageButton2.ImageUrl = "~/Images/star-off.png";


  String sql = "some sql";

        mysql.ExecuteNonQuery(sql);
    }
    else
    {
        starred = "1";
        ImageButton2.ImageUrl = "~/Images/star-on.png";
        String sql = "some sql";
        mysql.ExecuteNonQuery(sql);
    }
}
```

//Below is Main page's back code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebForm1" %>

<%@ Register src="ContentHolder.ascx" tagname="ContentHolder" tagprefix="ContentHolder" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" BackColor="#006699" Height="35px"
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Subscription"></asp:Label>
    </asp:Panel>  

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

//below is C#(ASP.net) Code of main page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    DataTable SrcData = mysql.executeSelect("Some SQL");
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            ContentHolder uc = (ContentHolder)LoadControl("ContentHolder.ascx");            
            form1.Controls.Add(uc);
        }
}
```

Comment: You have omitted the relevant part of the code. Where do you (re)create the dynamic controls? You know that you have to create them on every postback again, in `Page_Init` or `Page_Load`(at the latest) with the same ID's as before, don't you?

Comment: Hi Tim, I added my Whole code

Comment: Have you tried to move the code from Page_Load to Page_Init?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so i have tested your code ( with miner exception that you get there ) 
it works ( i removed all the images except ImageButton2 ) for debugging and it works.

so i would suggest that you do the same remove all images and stay with one, test it my guess
it will work, then add one other img and test, i can tell your very new to asp.net because you are using the design view to shape your page and that's why u get a lot of none breakabl space  in your code
i would really recommend to not work like this because you will never learn to code HTML properly like this, take your time dont skip steps read about HTML CSS JS to better understand
when client tech is better then server and vice versa, but thats my 50 cents :)

any way enjoy.

Comment: Thank you for your kind consideration, Liran.
It's true that I just get started the asp.net. I need a lot of study about Html.

Comment: all of us started at some point, its good you ask questions its part of learning, and we more then happy to help you :) @jeffhwang